# Google recaptcha client is throwing System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException in ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, invisible-recaptcha, .net-4.7.2, recaptcha-enterprise

> The type initializer for 'Grpc.Core.Internal.UserAgentStringProvider' threw an exception. (See inner exception for details.)
>
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Grpc.Core.Internal.UserAgentStringProvider' threw an exception.
>
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'Grpc.Core.Internal.PlatformApis' threw an exception.
>
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Multiple custom attributes  of the same type found.
>
> at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly element, Type
> attributeType, Boolean inherit)
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.get_FrameworkDescription()

Answer (score 1):

I mean the exception seems pretty clear:

```
Multiple custom attributes of the same type found.
```

That's all the help you can get without actual code.